# In Ubuntu, Check for existence of file, then... (not server)

Tags: linux

I need a script that will load something only if a file exists. want to hide this program if it's not installed, Pidgin. I have this right now to show the file;

```
let icon = new St.Icon({icon_name: "pidgin", icon_size: ICON_SIZE, icon_type: St.IconType.FULLCOLOR});
        this.filesystemItem = new MyPopupMenuItem(icon, _("Chat"));

        this.menu.addMenuItem(this.filesystemItem);
        this.filesystemItem.connect('activate', function(actor, event) {
            Main.Util.spawnCommandLine("pidgin");
        });
```

I need that only to load if the file: /usr/share/applications/Pidgin Internet Messenger.desktop is present. Please and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a bash file containing:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="/usr/share/applications/Pidgin Internet Messenger.desktop"
if [ -e "$filename" ]; then 
    echo "The file exists"
fi
```

and call it scriptName.sh

and run it:

```
bash scriptName.sh
```

Comment: nope doesn't work. Remember, this IS NOT on windows. this is on Ubuntu.

Comment: Add " double quotes to the $filename and it should.

Comment: Works for me, modified answer with how the bash script should look. What is happening when you try and run it? Are you getting errors or what?

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm doing... 
Check this out, this is the code I'm trying to do.
http://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/applets/view/24